# .groupby() in Pandas producing DataframeGroupby object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a data frame, `df`, that doesn't stack properly. I would believe that assigning my product of the `groupby()` function for Pandas dataframe would output a dataframe, but instead I get a `pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy` object.

Or, can you convert the object into a dataframe?

Here is my input, `df`:

```
                  Flavor      MONTH        Score
6                 Vanilla     March_2018   2.941176
7                 Chocolate   March_2018   7.692308
8                 Banana      March_2018   0.000000
23                Strawberry  March_2018   20.000000
```

Here is my command: `Score_df = df1.groupby(['Flavor','MONTH'])`

And I want to produce:

```
Score_df =

MONTH         March_2018
Flavor
Vanilla       2.941176
Chocolate     7.692308
Banana        0.000000
Strawberry    20.000000
```

but instead I get: `<pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x000002B7C2BE45F8>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
In [210]: df.pivot_table(index=df.Flavor, values='Score', columns='MONTH')
     ...: 
Out[210]: 
MONTH       March_2018
Flavor                
Banana        0.000000
Chocolate     7.692308
Strawberry   20.000000
Vanilla       2.941176
```